# Https requests from Ionic app returns 403 first time then it works

Tags: java, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, spring-boot

I implemented an app with Ionic. 
This app makes https requests to my server app that is done with Java8 and Spring Boot. In the browser everything works well but when I launch the app on my phone every request gets rejected with 403 Forbidden status only the first time. The same request succeeds the second time. 
For example: When I try to login with username and password, I press login and I get 403 Forbidden. I press it again, without changing anything and it succeeds. This behaviour is the same for all the requests that I make.
What can be the problem? I don't even know where to begin.

Update: Can this be because I am using an untrusted certificate for https requests? But if so, how come second time works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is normal behaviour by the browser and shouldn't worry you.

The browser just sends a normal http request, and the remote system sends back a 403 to say that it needs credentials. If it already has them, it sends the request again with the credentials, and if not it requests login credentials from the user.

All in a normal day's work.

Comment: Hi Mikkel, I don't think this is normal behaviour. From the browser is ok but when running the Ionic app in my phone, all the requests first return 403. This is not ok because the user gets error responses and then he needs to redo the requests. And I also have requests that run on controller start up, like find all entities and display them. This behaviour ruins the app